# How to preview Core Data objects in Canvas when using a CoreDataViewModel

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

The following code effectively uses the `@StateObject` and the `@ObservedObject` wrappers to capture changes from an `ObservableObject` view model. Everything is working as expected, except that I would like to be able to display dummy data in Canvas for designing purposes. As you can see from the code below, I'm able to create a `Car` object `inMemory` and effectively retrieve it in the `Preview` struct, my issue is when trying to display multiple cars, as you can see, to display multiple cars I had to duplicate the code for the `List` in the `Preview` struct for the `CarsView`. In the code below it doesn't seem like a big deal because I removed a lot of the code that makes the `List` but in my production code, I have a lot of code to customize the rows.

Is this really the best way to display data usually managed by a ViewModel?

Is there a way to display data without having to duplicate a lot of the `SwiftUI` code?

## SwiftUI Views

### Parent View / Content View

```
    struct ContentView: View {
        @StateObject var coreDataViewModel = CoreDataViewModel()

        var body: some View {
            
            TabView(selection: 1){
                
                CarsView(coreDataViewModel: coreDataViewModel)
                
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Cars")
                }.tag(1)

                // other tabs...
            }
        }
    }
```

### Second View / Cars View

My issue is that here, I'm duplicating the code from the main view in the Preview struct.

```
    struct CarsView: View {
        @ObservedObject var coreDataViewModel:CoreDataViewModel
        var body: some View {
            List {
                ForEach(coreDataViewModel.cars) { car in
                    // custom row to display cars
                }
            }
        }
    }

    struct CarsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
        static var previews: some View {

            CarsView(coreDataViewModel: CoreDataViewModel())
            
            
            let context = CoreDataManager.preview.container.viewContext
            let requestCar: NSFetchRequest<Car> = Car.fetchRequest()
            let fetchedCar = (try! context.fetch(requestCar).first)!
            
            let cars = [fetchedCar]
            // repeated code 
            List{
                ForEach(cars) { car in
                    Text(car.make ?? "")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

## Core Data

#### Entities and Attributes

Car

- make: String
- model: String

### Core Data Manager

```
    class CoreDataManager{

        static let instance = CoreDataManager()
        
        static var preview: CoreDataManager = {
            let result = CoreDataManager(inMemory: true)
            let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
            // new car
            let car = Car(context: viewContext)
            car.make = "Ford"
            car.model = "Mustang"
            
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
            
            }
            return result
        }()
        
        let container: NSPersistentContainer
        let context: NSManagedObjectContext
        
        init(inMemory: Bool = false){
            container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CoreDataContainer")
            
            if inMemory {
                container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
            }
            
            container.loadPersistentStores { (description, error) in
                if let error = error{
                    print("Error loading Core Data. \(error)")
                }
            }
            context = container.viewContext
        }
        
        func save(){
            do{
                try context.save()
                print("Saved successfully!")
            }catch let error{
                print("Error saving Core Data. \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
```

### Core Data View Model

```
    class CoreDataViewModel: ObservableObject{
        
        let manager = CoreDataManager.instance
        
        @Published var cars: [Car] = []
        
        init(){
            getCars()
        }
        
        // addCar, deleteCar, updateCar etc. methods...

        func getCars(){
            let request = NSFetchRequest<Car>(entityName: "Car")

            let sort = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Car.model, ascending: true)
            request.sortDescriptors = [sort]

            do{
                cars =  try manager.context.fetch(request)
            }catch let error{
                print("Error fetching businesses. \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        
        func save(){
            self.manager.save()
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I correctly understood, you are worried about the code duplication. Where is the duplication happening: in the model, in the view?

Comment: In the Preview of the CarsView, I have a comment that says `//repeated code`. Of course, here I'm only showing the minimum code for the List but it's a lot and when making changes to the UI updating both, the View and the Preview doesn't feel right.

Comment: It's there, look at the  Preview for the `CarsView`, the second view.  I left the CoreData code just for reference to have a better idea how I'm creating my objects.

Comment: Maybe there is an issue with Stackoverflow, I see the repeated code in the Preview of the CarsView, is the second snippet of code in my post.

Comment: The cause of your problem lies in the tight coupling between a View and CoreData. To get you an idea: don't name the view model "CoreDataViewModel" (_how_) - but instead name it "CarViewModel" - (_what_!) and _completely hide_ the fact that you are using managed objects and CoreData. Then for the preview (and tests), with the help of DI, you can set a "mock repository" _within_ CarViewModel when you create it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I will rename my ViewModel as suggested, makes sense.  FYI - This is my first time using the MVVM pattern and CoreData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of a preview is to use the ordinary view with some given data and not to duplicate the code from the actual view. Apart from that you seem to have much in place.

I would inject the Core Data manager class into the view model to start with:

```
class CoreDataViewModel: ObservableObject{        
    let manager: CoreDataManager
    
    @Published var cars: [Car] = []
    
    init(coreDataManager: CoreDataManager = .instance){
        self.manager = coreDataManager
        getCars()
    }
```

Then I would simplify the preview to

```
struct CarsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CarsView(coreDataViewModel: CoreDataViewModel(coreDataManager: .preview))
    }
}
```

You are already creating one Car object in the `preview` so why not do that in a loop, here I have moved it into a separate function that can be called from inside the `preview` declaration or separately

```
#if DEBUG
extension CoreDataManager {
    func createMockCars() {
        for i in 1...5 {
             let car = Car(context: self.context)
             car.make = "Make \(i)"
             car.model = "Model \(i)"
        }
        try! self.context.save()
    }
}
#endif
```

As mentioned in one of the comments you should consider renaming your view model to something to do with cars like CarsViewModel or CarListViewModel.

Comment: @ Joakim Danielson - I cannot thank you enough, this is working great with all of my data objects in CoreData, awesome!.  Unfortunately, I'm not really familiar with Dependency Injection.  Quick question, besides helping with the previews in Canvas, are there other benefits by injecting the Core Data manager class into the view model?  Here I'm just trying to have a better understanding of the injection we made to the view model. Better yet, is that really considered Dependency Injection?

Comment: Yes this is dependency injection and as you see with this implementation you don't have a hard coded dependency between the view model and the CoreDataManager class so you can inject different types. This is not only useful for previews but also for testing. To take this one step further one would use a protocol instead so you could inject any type that conforms to this protocol.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and the good advice. I will take a closer look at DI. Thanks a lot for all of your help!